# "Failed to Configure TFS project collection" while configuring test controller

Tags: tfs

I am getting an error while configuring test controller:

```
Failed to configure team project collection.
```

I have tried to look all question and answered posted on this blog but could not find one exact answer for resolution.
I am using my windows local user credentials and password.

Comment: You will need to post more info than this I think.

Comment: I am using local account to login (same account I use login into TFS web) and I do not have admin rights with my account .I have installed Test manager 2013 which comes with Visual studio test professional 2013 .I Need Test constroller in order to use full testing capabilities. I hope these details can help answer questions

Comment: I meant are you running the tool 'As administrator' as in right click the icon and select that. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593699.aspx you will need 'To connect TFS to Release Management, you must be a member of the Release Manager role in Release Management. To manage permissions in TFS, you must be a member of the Project Collection Administrators group. To add a user account, you must be a member of the Windows Administrators group (local user) or the Domain Administrators group (domain account).'. Do you meet those requirements?

Comment: Thanks for answering . I just got my user registered under window administrators group . Let me try to reconfigure again and see if it  works.

Comment: I'm curious if it is just a permissions issue

Comment: Hi Mike: I don't think its user permission issue 
 I have done following things to do configuration . I hope it helps you find an clear answer .
 1: I already have TFS 2012 installed on my local machine
2: I have installed MTM which comes with Visual studio test professional 2013
 3: I have installed test controller 2012 and next step is configuration
 which gives error ” Failed to Register with TFS Team project collection ”
and I am pretty sure my user have all access and permission granted now .
 Please let me know what are the things I am missing ?

Comment: Are you a member of the project collection admins?

Comment: Yes I am member of Project collection admins .

Comment: Maybe (not sure) you can't use test 2013 with a 2012 test controller.

Comment: Issue is resolved . I have reinstalled 2012 test manager and I had to stop Citrix Xml service manually . Thank you